# regex: match until the first ] character is found

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match untill the first occurence of ] is found but can't seem to make it work, if someone could help me figure this out.

The string I'm matching against:

```
[plugin:tabs][tab title="test"]Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sit amet nisl nisl. Ut interdum libero vitae quam ultricies et lacinia elit aliquet. Praesent tincidunt, sem tempus feugiat feugiat, turpis tellus scelerisque erat, sit amet feugiat neque arcu ac lectus. Sed at mi et elit interdum scelerisque vitae eu felis.[/tab][/plugin]
```

What it should match:

```
[plugin:tabs]
```

What it keeps matching:

```
[plugin:tabs][tab title="test"]
```

The regex:

```
(\[plugin:(?<identifier>[^\s]+)(?<parameters>.*?)\])
```

EDIT:
What it should also match:

```
[plugin:tabs test="test"]
```

Comment: Maybe using `\w` (word characters) instead of `[^\s]` (non-whitespace characters) does already suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this here

```
(\[plugin:(?<identifier>[^\]\s]+)(?<parameters>.*?)\])
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vi13)

This avoids additionally to the whitespace characters also the `]` character in the first named group.

If you don't need the first capturing group you can make it a non-capturing group by adding `?:` right after the opening bracket.

```
(?:\[plugin:(?<identifier>[^\]\s]+)(?<parameters>.*?)\])
```

To avoid that the space in between is captured by the second group, just match optional whitespace between the two groups

```
(?:\[plugin:(?<identifier>[^\]\s]+)\s*(?<parameters>.*?)\])
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vi2s)

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the space infront of the 2nd capture group?

Comment: @luastoned I added a regex to my answer, just match it between the two groups.

Comment: I get it, I tried to remove the first `\s` after `\]` which didn't work, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add `?` like so (lazy match, will match as few characters as possible):

```
(\[plugin:(?<identifier>[^\s]+?)(?<parameters>.*?)\])
                              ^
```

Although the `(?<parameters>.*?)` part is unnecessary then.

So your final Regex would look like this:

```
(\[plugin:(?<identifier>[^\s]+?)\])
```

€dit: See @stema's answer.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that the parameters are very important, see my edited question

Comment: @krike I don't quite understand, you want to match the plugin name and `tab title="test"` or what?

Comment: the plugin name with optionaly attributes but not the [tab title="test"] that comes after it

Answer (score 0):

With any language that supports [lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that will be your easiest solution.

```
/(^(?<!])*)/
```